# cabasicanimation stop animating when low battery alert comes on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cabasicanimation

I'm using UIViewBasicanimation. It works fine unless low battery alert is received, then the  animation stops/pauses and does not restart after closing. All other buttons are working fine except the animation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:10];

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

[animatingObj setFrame:CGRectMake(100,900,100,100)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```